# How web request executed via internet?

Tags: http, soap, request, message

I want to know how web request executed while requesting any information from other server. I want to know internal of this message processing means when we click any button on web page then how it converted to GET/POST request in proper message format inclucing SOAP etc. Is there any link or book from where i can get these info. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Search on w3.org for specifications for ex. [Soap specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-part1/#intro)